# Finding equinox and solstice times with astropy

Tags: scipy, astropy

I would like to use the astropy package to compute the time of equinoxes and solstices. I have worked before with the pyephem package, and it provides easy functions exactly for this: one can, for example, say

```
>>> print(ephem.next_equinox(ephem.now()))
2019/9/23 07:50:14
```

and get the time of the next equinox. However, there are no such functions in astropy, so I thought I might try to compute the times by the definition: the vernal equinox is the moment when the ecliptic longitude of the Sun is zero; the summer solstice is the moment when the ecliptic longitude of the Sun is 90° etc.

So it seems that getting the ecliptic longitude of the Sun would be the essential step, and then I could somehow solve that function for time:

```
def sunEclipticLongitude(t):
    sun = astropy.coordinates.get_body('sun', t)
    eclipticOfDate = astropy.coordinates.GeocentricTrueEcliptic(equinox=t)
    sunEcliptic = sun.transform_to(eclipticOfDate)
    return sunEcliptic.lon.deg
```

My first thought was to use something from `scipy.optimize` to solve this function for time, but at this point, I got stuck. The Sun's longitude is an angle, so there are obviously many solutions for lon=0 (this year's equinox, next year's equinox ...) How do I find the *next* time (from a particular origin, for example now) when the Sun's longitude is zero? How do I find the *previous* time when it was zero? Also, the vernal equinox seems to be a particularly nasty case for solving, since the function has a discontinuity at that point – it jumps from 360 to 0. How to handle that?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the optimization strategy will still work for periodic functions, but the solution will depend on your optimization starting point. Just pick a point that's already pretty close. You know that equinoxes are Mar 21 and Sep 20 (or something like that), and solstices are June 21 and Dec 21. Pick an arbitrary time of day on those dates, and you'll find the right solution.

As for the discontinuity in the angle, it isn't really there... It's just that in this particular convention you elect to represent angles as numbers between 0 and 360 degrees. But mathematically, the angle of 361 degrees means exactly the same thing as 1 degrees and has just as much right to exist.

As a result, continuous periodic functions like sin(), cos() etc. will not show any discontinuity at that value of the angle (or any other value of the angle that you pick as minimum or maximum).

Comment: Taking known dates as starting points is a useful heuristic approach that works well for the current era, but would likely fail for dates a few thousand years in the future or past. Not that I would be particularly worried about those – just an observation.

Comment: As for the discontinuity, I agree that it's only apparent, but it looks quite real to the optimization algorithm and I'm worried that it would fail to converge on such points. One solution that I thought of is to represent angles as points in the complex plane [cos(phi), i*sin(phi)] and then take the (squared) distance between them as the function to minimize. Such a function has no discontinuities and the minima represent the solutions that I'm looking for.

Comment: Now that I think of it again, my argument about the dates might be a moot point. They *do* stay almost the same within a period of several thousand years, so for all practical intents and purposes, this would be good enough. Still, I'm wondering if there is a way to force the optimizer to search for solutions in a particular direction (e.g. only in the positive direction from the starting point).

Comment: @AndrejLajovic: the calendar is designed to stay as close as possible to the solar cycle - that's what all the rules for leap years are about. So even after tens of thousands of years the equinoxes/solstices should stay about the same. Regarding the apparent discontinuity: the algorithm can't notice it because it simlpy doesn't know about it - it'll just go over 360 degrees as if it wasn't a limit (mathematically, it isn't). So for example you'll get an answer of 365 degrees or 376 degrees, which is equivalent to 5 or 16 degrees - but periodic functions will work just fine with either values.

Comment: The current leap year rules do have a residual error, so the equinox will *eventually* drift unless further corrections are made. However, this is only a concern when dealing with dates extremely far in the future or past, so it's not really a huge practical limitation. Regarding the discontinuity: the angle is not the input to `sunEclipticLongitude`, it's the output. When the input (time) crosses a certain value, the output jumps from 360 to 0. I'm trying to solve this function for time at which the resulting angle would be 0.

Comment: @AndrejLajovic: I see. If the angle is the output, the discontinuity does matter. Still easily solvable though - just use SIN^2(THETA / 2) as your squared error function in the optimization, where THETA is the angle difference between your two angles. Don't use the THETA^2 as the error directly.

Answer (score 0):

As you expected, the syzygys can be located using `scipy.optimize`, via a root-finding function, as in the code snippet below. But rather than looking for the *next* syzygy, it looks for the *nearest* one, by picking points 44 days before and after the given date and expecting that there will be one syzygy in between those dates. Since Earth doesn't have [seasons shorter than 88 days within plus-or-minus 50,000 years](https://individual.utoronto.ca/kalendis/seasons.htm#seasons), that's hopefully a pretty safe bet, and the astropy ephemerides aren't accurate for that long anyway. I employed `sin(angle*2)` in the (poorly named) `linearize(angle)` code below to convert ecliptic longitudes to a function which crosses zero at each quadrant.

The code is also in a gist, which might get refined: see [find syzygy / equinox / solstice with astropy](https://gist.github.com/nealmcb/858bbc14e9a40b5d88f1428fe53456d0)

```py
# Find the nearest syzygy (solstice or equinox) to a given date.
# Solution for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55838712/finding-equinox-and-solstice-times-with-astropy
# TODO: need to ensure we're using the right sun position functions for the syzygy definition....

import math
from astropy.time import Time, TimeDelta
import astropy.coordinates
from scipy.optimize import brentq
from astropy import units as u


# We'll usually find a zero crossing if we look this many days before and after
# given time, except when it is is within a few days of a cross-quarter day.
# But going over 50,000 years back, season lengths can vary from 85 to 98 days!
#  https://individual.utoronto.ca/kalendis/seasons.htm#seasons
delta = 44.0


def mjd_to_time(mjd):
    "Return a Time object corresponding to the given Modified Julian Date."

    return Time(mjd, format='mjd', scale='utc')


def sunEclipticLongitude(mjd):
    "Return ecliptic longitude of the sun in degrees at given time (MJD)"

    t = mjd_to_time(mjd)
    sun = astropy.coordinates.get_body('sun', t)
    # TODO: Are these the right functions to call for the definition of syzygy? Geocentric? True?
    eclipticOfDate = astropy.coordinates.GeocentricTrueEcliptic(equinox=t)
    sunEcliptic = sun.transform_to(eclipticOfDate)
    return sunEcliptic.lon.deg


def linearize(angle):
    """Map angle values in degrees near the quadrants of the circle
    into smooth functions crossing zero, for root-finding algorithms.
    Note that for angles near 90 or 270, increasing angles yield decreasing results
    >>> linearize(5) > 0 > linearize(355)
    True
    >>> linearize(95) > 0 > linearize(85)
    False
    """

    return math.sin(math.radians(angle * 2))


def map_syzygy(t):
    "Map times into linear functions crossing zero at each syzygy"

    return linearize(sunEclipticLongitude(t))


def find_nearest_syzygy(t):
    """Return the precise Time of the nearest syzygy to the given Time,
    which must be within 43 days of one syzygy"
    """

    syzygy_mjd = brentq(map_syzygy, t.mjd - delta, t.mjd + delta)

    syzygy = mjd_to_time(syzygy_mjd)
    syzygy.format = 'isot'
    return syzygy


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()

    t0 = Time('2019-09-23T07:50:10', format='isot', scale='utc')

    td = TimeDelta(1.0 * u.day)

    seq = t0 + td * range(0, 365, 15)

    for t in seq:
        try:
            syzygy = find_nearest_syzygy(t)
        except ValueError as e:
            print(f'{e=}, {t.value=}, {t.mjd-delta=}, {map_syzygy(t.mjd-delta)=}')
            continue
        print(f'{t.value=}, {syzygy.value=}, {sunEclipticLongitude(syzygy)=}')
```